# retrieving data from database according to query conditions

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
    "_id":{"$id":"61b5eb36029b48135465e766"},
"name":"push-ups","link":"https://google.com",
"image":"https://google.com",
"gender":["0","1","2"],
"goal":["lw","gw","sf"],
"age":60,
"excersietype":"chest",
"__v":0
```

this is how my data is stored in database
and I want to fetch data according to  3 condition

I got 3 queries from front gender goal and age and according to that I have to retrieve data

```
 const gender = req.query.gender;
    const age = req.query.age;
    const goal = req.query.goal
    const level = req.query.level

    if (level==='fb'){
        const getdata = new Forbeg.find({gender:{$in:gender}},{age:{$lte:age}},{goal:{$in:goal}});
        console.log(getdata)
    }
```

Is this a good way to find the data because I am getting error

```
 UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: `Model.find()` cannot run without a model as `this`. Make sure you are not calling `new Model.find()`
```

I am getting above error while fetching

Comment: I resolved the error I didn't use await. but after this still I haven't receving any data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is explicit : `Make sure you are not calling 'new Model.find()'`. Use `const getdata = Forbeg.find(...)`.

However, you will immediately run into the next problem, as Mongoose models return thenables (Promise-like). `console.log(getdata)` will log `Promise<pending>`. You need to *resolve* your database call, either by doing

```
Forbeg.find(...).then( getdata => console.log(getData));
```

or (much more better!):

```
const getdata = await Forbeg.find(...);
console.log(getdata)
```

Even better, add `.lean()` to get simple JSON data instead of an array of Mongoose objects (faster), and `.exec()` to get a true Promise instead of a thenable :

```
const getdata = await Forbeg.find(...).lean().exec();
console.log(getdata)
```

Comment: I have some more problem will you please help me?

Comment: Ha, if you have another problem, then you have to create a new question, so everybody can try to help you :)

Comment: Yeah I have posted just now, please check on my profile

Answer (score 0):

Remove new operator

```
const getData = Forbeg.find({gender:{$in:gender}},{age:{$lte:age}},{goal:{$in:goal}});
```